# Проблема с “FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings”

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine-4

VS2017 жалуется на "FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings не определён". В UE4 всё компилируется без проблем и объект создаётся на сцене. Но студия со времен начинает жаловаться на переменную, которая ссылается на данный тип с ошибкой:

> Ошибка (активно)  E0434   не удается инициализировать ссылку типа
>   "FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings &" (квалифицируется как неконстантная)
>   со значением типа "FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings"

Проблема появилась в следствии использования документации по UE4 [Первый урок](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Tutorials/Components/1). Добавил заголовочник с именем проекта, изменил "MinimalCore.h" на "Engine.h" (в сети прочитал что это лучше, так как компилится быстрее).

```
main.h
#include "Engine.h"
```

Далее добавил строку ниже, при добавление VS2017 начала жаловаться на `GENERATED_BODY()`, что как бы по дефолту в каждом проекте. Гуглил ответы были, пробовал не особо помогло, но в конце концов руками исправил. Исправил просто поменяв либу то, что выше.

```
...
UParticleSystemComponent* OurParticleSystem;
...
```

После довабил ещё код (первые две строки дефолт в конструкторе и методе) и вроде бы всё ок.

```
ASpherePawn::ASpherePawn()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ASpherePawn::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    USphereComponent* SphereComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
    RootComponent = SphereComponent;
    SphereComponent->InitSphereRadius(40.0f);
    SphereComponent->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Pawn"));
}
```

И тут студия начала жаловаться на `FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings` не определён. Перейдя по ошибке в заголовочник `"VertexFactory.h"` студия выдала ошибку, что `ShaderBindings` не определён. Участок кода из `"VertexFactory.h"` привёл ниже

```
void GetElementShaderBindings(
        const class FSceneInterface* Scene,
        const FSceneView* View,
        const class FMeshMaterialShader* Shader,
        bool bShaderRequiresPositionOnlyStream,
        ERHIFeatureLevel::Type FeatureLevel,
        const FVertexFactory* VertexFactory,
        const struct FMeshBatchElement& BatchElement,
        FMeshDrawSingleShaderBindings& ShaderBindings,
        FVertexInputStreamArray& VertexStreams
        ) const
    {
        if (Parameters)
        {
            checkSlow(VertexFactory->GetType() == VertexFactoryType);
            checkSlow(View || VertexFactoryType->SupportsCachingMeshDrawCommands());
            Parameters->GetElementShaderBindings(Scene, View, Shader, bShaderRequiresPositionOnlyStream, FeatureLevel, VertexFactory, BatchElement, ShaderBindings, VertexStreams);
        }
    }
```

Сам вопрос: С чем может быть связанна данная проблема в VS2017, так как код компилируется в EU4? Прежде настроил VS2017 по гайду данному в документации к UE4.

Comment: Что значит "код компилируется в EU4"? Он что, использует компилятор, отличный от студийного? Ну и стоит иметь ввиду, что ковыряние в UE требует уверенного владения C++. И, конечно, не стоит выполнять всякие рандомные советы из интернета, сути которых вы не понимаете.

Comment: Как я писал выше я исправил либу обратно чтобы заработало. Только не понимаю почему он жалуется при смене либы на объекты входящие и в ту и другую либу (гуглил тип переменной и либы и там и там есть объекты). Больше всего удивило, что USphereComponent не находит при подключении MinimalCore, а это дефолт которые позволяет создавать сферу.
Я не копался в исходниках UE, я поправил либу в заголовочнике своего проекта.
Насчёт компилятора - честно я не знаю использует ли UE4 компиль студии. Мне казалось что у UE4 собственный так как UE4 может работать не только с VS.

Comment: Есть такая народная мудрость - 'работает - не трогай!' :) разумнее вернуть все как было, и забыть о той мелкой оптимизации которую вы пытались внедрить, по скорости сборки..

Comment: @NewView не спорю, но проблема в том что добавив новую или вернув прежнюю проблема выше не исправилась)

Comment: Тогда, стандартный подход, удаление папки `obj` чистка всех прекомпилируемых заголовков, итд